# How can i pass previously declared variables by using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I need to operate a change of text on my HTML whenever the value selected in the drop down list changes.

My problem : it seems i am unable to pass parameters to `Modif` by using the `addEventListener` , note that without the `addEventListener` it works fine, the variables i am trying to pass exist but are not global.

The HTML select :

```
<select id="type_affectation" class="form-control">
   <option value="Aucun">Choix Affectation</option>
   <option value="0">Prévisionnel / Validé</option>
   <option value="1">Maladie / Absence</option>
   <option value="2">Congé Payé / Récup</option>
   <option value="3">Ecole</option>
</select>
```

My function :

```
function Modif(span, plannings, planning, plannifie, longueur, colonne, case){
    const affectation = $("#type_affectation").val();
    let retour = document.createElement("br");
    console.log("plage dans Modif : " + plannings[planning][plannifie].id_plage);
    while (plannings[planning][plannifie].id_plage == casee){
        // var plageText = document.createTextNode("");

        if (affectation == "Aucun" || affectation == 0){
            if(plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 0 || plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 1 || plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 8 || plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 9){
                plageText = document.createTextNode(plannings.nom_employe + "/" + plannings.libelle);
                // var plageText = document.createTextNode(plannings[planning][plannifie].nom_employe + " / " + plannings[planning][plannifie].libelle);
            }
        }else if(affectation == 1){
            if(plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 6 || plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 3){
                plageText = document.createTextNode(plannings.nom_employe + "/" + plannings.libelle);
            }
        }else if(affectation == 2){
            if(plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 5 || plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 7){
                plageText = document.createTextNode(plannings.nom_employe + "/" + plannings.libelle);
            }
        }else{
            if(plannings[planning][plannifie].id_affectation == 2){
                plageText = document.createTextNode(plannings.nom_employe + "/" + plannings.libelle);
            }
        }                             
        span.appendChild(plageText);
        span.appendChild(retour);

        if(plannifie < longueur-1){
            // console.log("plannifier : " + plannifie);
            plannifie++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    colonne.appendChild(span);

}
```

The call of the function

```
var affectation_modif = $("#type_affectation")[0];
affectation_modif.addEventListener('change', function() {
      Modif(span, plannings, planning, plannifie, longueur, colonne, casee);
}
```

This is the plannings object :
[image]

Comment: Could you try `console.log(span, plannings, planning, plannifie, longueur, colonne)` before your call to Modif inside the addEventListener and see if the variables do exist in that scope ?

Comment: Nothing is being console.logged

Comment: Can you check your console for errors - `$["#type_affectation"][0]` is not valid syntax for jquery.  If you're going to use native `addEventListener` rather than jquery event handler, then use native methods to get the element in the first place.

Comment: @Bob if nothing is being console.logged then the function is just not being called. See if you have errors like freedomn suggested.

Comment: Yes, in my real code the jQuery statement  ```$["#type_affectation"][0]``` is actually ```$("#type_affectation")[0]```, my bad, recopied it badly. However, when i ```console.log("plage dans Modif : " + plannings[planning][plannifie].id_plage); ``` the error returned is : rpv.js:177 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined  . And when i ```console.log(span + " / " + plannings+ " / " + planning + " / " + plannifie + " / " +  longueur + " / " + colonne);``` nothing appears

Comment: Maybe i should pass ```id_plage``` too maybe, but it is value inside ```plannings[planning][plannifie]``` so it should retrieve it right?

Comment: the error of property 0 of undefined is weird cos it means that $('#...') is undefined which means something is wrong with $
Anyway, you could use `document.getElementById('type_affectation')` but do make sure it's called after the dom has finished loading
`window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {`
`  document.getElementById('...').addEventListener(....`
`});`

Comment: @SélimAchour The ```$("#type_affecation")[0]``` isnt the problem because when i ```console.log(affectation)``` (which is ```$("#type_affectation").val```) i get the updated value whenever i change the value in the drop down list

Comment: Please post a [mcve] - You have an X/Y problem. Your whole code can likely be streamlined in such a way that maintenance is much simpler. What you have shown so far is full of code smells and scope issues

Comment: For example what is casee in `while (plannings[planning][plannifie].id_plage == casee){`

Comment: Also there is no difference in ANY Of the `plageText = document.createTextNode(plannings.nom_employe + "/" + plannings.libelle);` - why the huge number of ifs and duplication of code?

Comment: @mplungjan ```plannings``` is an ```array ``` containing 7 arrays (```planning```) which also has some arrays (```plannifie```), then ```span``` is an object type ```span```, colonne is an object type ```div``` and everything else is ```int``` . Btw i integrated ```casee``` which is also ```int``` in the parameters. I think it's ```.id_plage``` which is causing problem, ```id_plage``` is one of the 10 keys containing a value inside ```plannifie```

Comment: But all plageText  will be the same regardless of values. What is the point? And the code can be changed to a few lines

Comment: @mplungjan The ```plageText``` conditions are there because i want to show something according to the ```id.affectation```, however, what can i do for ```.id_plage```? In my logic, it should retrieve it even if i dont declare it

Comment: I cannot even start to guess until I have a [mcve] I cannot guess where you get stuff from - show HTML and the plannings object

Comment: @Bob Please post 1. Plannings object AS CODE, NOT PICTURE 2. HTML that includes the "colonne" 3. script that defines colonne, and the other parameters AND you are misspelling case casee in the script

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes down to syntax errors and undeclared variables:

```
// You need parenthesis around the element ID, not brackets
var affectation_modif = $("#type_affectation")[0];
affectation_modif.addEventListener('change', function() {
      // All of these arguments must be defined somewhere before
      // you can use them.
      Modif(span, plannings, planning, plannifie, longueur, colonne);
}); // <-- You forgot to close the method call with ");"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
$("#type_affectation").on("change", function() {       
   Modif(span, plannings, planning, plannifie, longueur, colonne); 
})
```

assuming

```
span, plannings, planning, plannifie, longueur, colonne
```

are available in the scope of the execution

Comment: Yes this is the problem, when i ```console.log``` them inside the function, nothing appears

Comment: So please post a [mcve] with relevant HTML. Click edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor and post relevant PURE HTML and script with whatever frameworks you have